# How does Grpc Server perform and modify objects in WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, grpc, communication, .net-framework-version

I'm new to GRpc and trying to implement the following:

1. I have a WPF application which is running on .Net Framework 4.7.2
2. I have a Mobile application(used MAUI) which has to communicate to WPF application.

To enable the communication between these 2 applications, I have created a separate GRpc server application, and using the Process.Start() invoking the GRpc Server application from within the WPF application.

My Mobile application is able to communicate with the GRpc server application, but from GRpc server application, I'm unable to update anything in the WPF application.

How to achieve this?

I have created a Singleton class (MyManager.cs) in .NetStandard 2.0 application and added the reference to the GRpc server application and WPF application.

```
namespace CommonHelper
    {
        public delegate string SelectItemHandler(string guid);
        public class MyManager
        {
            private static MyManager _instance;
            public event SelectItemHandler SelectItemByGuid;

            private MyManager() { }

            public static MyManager Instance => _instance ?? (_instance = new MyManager());

            public string SelectItem(string deviceUniqueId)
            {
                var result = string.Empty;
                if (SelectItemByGuid != null)
                    result = SelectItemByGuid(deviceUniqueId);
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
```

In the GRpc Server application, inside the rpc call:

```
public override async Task<ItemResponse> SelectItem(IAsyncStreamReader<ItemRequest> requestStream, ServerCallContext context)
        {
            string itemName = string.Empty;
            ItemRequest itemRequest = new ItemRequest();
            while (await requestStream.MoveNext())
            {
                itemRequest = requestStream.Current;
            }
            itemName = MyManager.Instance.SelectItem(itemRequest.UniqueId);
            return new ItemResponse { Label = itemName };
        }
```

Inside my Viewmodel in the WPF application,
On click of a button, I'm hosting the GRpc server application using the Process.Start("executable of the GRpc server application")

I'm doing the following the same ViewModel
`MyManager.Instance.SelectItemByGuid += InstanceOnSelectItemByGuid;`

```
private string InstanceOnSelectItemByGuid(string uinqueId)
{
   //Since I have the guid, i will be able to select the item and display it in the view.
}
```

But from the GRpc server, my method in the viewmodel is not invoked.

This is how i'm invoking the GRpc server, unable to use WebApplication type in WPF application directly:

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
            builder.WebHost.UseUrls("http://192.168.29.247:5116;https://192.168.29.247:7224");
            builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
            {
                options.ConfigureEndpointDefaults(def => { def.Protocols = HttpProtocols.Http2; });
            });
            builder.WebHost.UseKestrel();
            builder.Services.AddGrpc();
            var app = builder.Build();
            app.MapGrpcService<GreeterService>();
            app.MapGet("/",
                () =>
                    "Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a gRPC client. To learn how to create a client, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086909");
            app.Run();
        }
    }
```

Comment: "On click of a button, I'm hosting the GRpc server application using the Process.Start("executable of the GRpc server application")" - if you're hosting the gRPC server in a different process, how do you expect the WPF application to "see" any changes? If they're in different processes, there will be two different instances of MyManager... Basically, you need to have *one* process for your WPF app + gRPC server. (And be careful of threading...)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.
I suspected the same but unable to launch the Grpc server from with in the WPF application. Is there a way I can launch the GRpc server application without the Process.Start()

Comment: Just call the code that starts the server from within your WPF application. I do this in one of my own projects - not gRPC, but a different ASP.NET Core server. We can't really give more advice than that without knowing what you've tried.

Comment: I have added the code block on how I'm invoking the GRpc server. I had to create a separate application  as I didn't find a way to host without using the WebApplication type which is not available in WPF.

Comment: "I had to create a separate application as I didn't find a way to host without using the WebApplication type which is not available in WPF" - you just need `<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />`. I suggest you create a new question asking "How do you start an ASP.NET Core server in a WPF app" (after doing some research to see whether there's already such a question).